# How do you install xpilot-ng-client-x11 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I went to start the xpilot client after upgrading to 20.04 from 19.10 but the client is no longer installed nor does it (xpilot-ng-client-x11) appear in the package list. The server and extras are installed. I tried to install the required packages from V19.10 deb files  but ran into problems with an unsatisfied dependency - libut0 needs to be >=1.01 ... which it is... but the package manager doesn't think so.

So I am stuck. Does anyone have a solution or do I need to downgrade my OS ... because Xpilot is a must for me.

regards,
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download packages from Ubuntu 19.10 manually:

**for client -**

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xpilot-ng/xpilot-ng-client-x11_4.7.3-2.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xpilot-ng/xpilot-ng-common_4.7.3-2.3ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-irc/python-irc_8.5.3+dfsg-4_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./xpilot*.deb ./python-irc_8.5.3+dfsg-4_all.deb
```

**for server -**

```
# for server
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xpilot-ng/xpilot-ng-server_4.7.3-2.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./xpilot-ng-server_4.7.3-2.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly and XPilot is worrking on 20.04. It  is very interesting as I don't really understand Ubuntu repositories which do seem to be fantastic. I will try and learn more about them but am also wondering why the xpilot client was not included in 20.04 yet the server was  included ... maybe an oversight or perhaps an issue with the client that needs to be ironed out ...?

Comment: It looks like Python 2 is the reason for removing client package. Python 2 is now deprecated.